# DOS Graphics vs. Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, graphics, dos

So I am trying to recreate a DOS program my boss made a while ago. It draws a series of lines that end up making a picture.

His program takes 2 XYZ points, converts them to XY and draws a line between the two using DOS graphics. He claims he only draws one line every frame. Well his program plotted 1,700,000 lines in 55 seconds. That works out to be roughly 31,000 frames per second.

I have done the same thing (1,700,000 lines) using OpenGL in Windows and I can only push out around 1,000 frames per second. His program runs on DOS with 1.0Ghz processor, and what I imagine to be a very old graphics controller. I am running my program on an i5 at 2.6 Ghz, 8Gb RAM, Intel Graphics 4000, 2GB VRAM.

Does this sound right to anyone? I feel like he must be plotting more than one point in each frame. Is it because Windows just has more going on than DOS and my program can't run that fast? Is there any way to get OpenGL graphics to run at those frame rates on my computer?

Comment: What is the Point if your eyes cannot see that fast? If you want to complete the calculations faster, separate it from display.

Comment: Pixel graphics is not quite the same as characters in a console ;p I mean, if nothing else, the resolution of your boss's program will be _orders of magnitude_ lower than that of yours.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I understand the difference in resolution, that is something I had thought about, but I am not sure what you mean by 'Pixel graphics is not quite the same as characters in a console.' What do characters have to do with it?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring: My interpretation was that your boss's program essentially drew ASCII art with underscores and vertical pipes ("draws a series of lines"), which was the most common way to draw stuff in DOS. If this is not correct, please expand in your question. (This also suggests that you _don't_ see what I meant by resolution; not at all).

Comment: No, he draws actual lines. The program I believe is called DOS Graphics. What do you mean by resolution then?

Comment: @TheBlindSpring: Imagine he were drawing ASCII art on a 80x24 console grid. That has a resolution of 80x24. A far cry from the 800x600 or whatever you're doing with your pixels.

Comment: How are you rendering the lines? If you render one line per frame using glBegin-glEnd, then your performance looks about right. If you load the line vertices into GPU memory (using a VBO) and use glDrawElements to render them at once, then you will get one or two orders of magnitude better performance. There are ways to go even faster.

Comment: I am using a VBO, however, I am not drawing everything at once. I  draw 1 line every frame to simulate the how show the image actually BEING drawn.

Comment: "He claims he only draws one line every frame." There isn't any notion of a "frame" in the context you are describing. It is a completely meaningless statement.

Comment: I do not know how 'frames' work in DOS (or if they even exist), but I am referring to a frame as in a single call to OpenGL display function. I only draw 1 line each call (frame). So instead of the picture just popping up, the user actually watches the drawing being animated.

Comment: You, actually, compare the speed of *printing* characters on the old VGA screen using raw OS's capabilities with the speed of *drawing* on high-resolution display using, though, very performance effective, but still complex application OpenGl. This is not correct way to compare (as @derhass pointed out).

Comment: @TheBlindSpring: As I said there _are_ no frames. What these DOS apps did was directly writing into the mapped video RAM. And stuff became visible the next time the RAMDAC read out the specific part of the screen you were drawing. So with any notion of animation frames, there were something like 60 to 120, depending on the Monitor. In principle it is the same as using a single-buffered GL visual, and drawing _all_ lines with a _single_ drawing call. The lines will apprear on the screen as soon as they reached the framebuffer, but not before they were sent to the display.

Comment: @TheBlindSpring: So you get the same 60 to 120 Hz animation speed as you get with your DOS graohics, just the GL drawing will be orders of magnitude faster. You can artificially slow down the process by using a draw call per line (and I still think you can draw 1.7 million lines in much less than 55 seconds). Insiting of using a "display function" - which is neither a concept of OpenGL or of graphics in general - isn't changing that much then. Still more overhead, but will not slow down things too much.

Comment: @TheBlindSpring: It just does get totally meaningless if you add new operations like swapping or clearing buffers to your loop, which the original DOS certainly did not do. So what we're down to here is that the DOS thing did ~31000 sw-rasterized lines per second. That's nothing compared to what a GPU nowadays can do.